# Solving a Bloch sphere where alpha is imaginary

Tags: bloch-sphere

$$
\begin{array}{l}
|\psi\rangle=\frac{\sqrt{3 i}}{2}|0\rangle-\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle \\
|\psi\rangle=0.924|0\rangle-0.382 i |1\rangle
\end{array}
$$

Basically I’m trying to convert these to a standard form/Bloch sphere. I thought the Bloch sphere was supposed to use real numbers so that $\cos(\theta/2)=\alpha$ and same for $\beta$. But I’m not sure how you would do it with complex numbers and it’s really hard to find resources. Thanks!

Comment: can i just multiple the whole thing by i because psi equals 1 so it wouldnt change anything??

Answer (score 3):

The bloch sphere can be confusing and intimidating for sure. There are a couple of key things I always try to remember when I want to work with it.

1. Euler's formula is always our friend: $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$
2. The convention of using half-angles makes the math simpler when you start to manipulate quantum states around the bloch sphere. But the bloch sphere is just a spherical coordinate system with radius of 1. These spherical coordinates are where $\theta$ and $\psi$ come from. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) is helpful to keep $\theta$ and $\frac{\theta}{2}$ straight.
3. For a single qubit, quantum state, the global-phase is 'immeasureable'. This means we can really only measure the relative phase difference between the two eigenstates $\lvert 0 \rangle \text{ and } \lvert 1 \rangle$. So that means that $\lvert \psi \rangle $ and $e^{i\gamma}\lvert\psi\rangle$ will 'measure' the same $\forall \gamma \in [0,2\pi)$. We say that $\psi$ and $e^{i\gamma}\lvert\psi\rangle$  are equvialent "up to a global phase".  This lets us 'arbitrarily' change the global phase without changing any outcomes.

It is nice if our quantum state is already in the form
$$
\psi\text{ = }\alpha\lvert 0\rangle + \beta e^{\phi i}\lvert 1 \rangle \text{   } \alpha,\beta,\phi \in \mathbb{R}
$$
We can then get $\theta\text{ or }\frac{\theta}{2}$ from $\alpha$.  If our state is not in that form, such as your examples, we are going to exploit a global phase to map $\psi$ to an equivalent state $\psi^{'}$ which will be in the form we want.

So we start with:
$$\psi\text{ = }\alpha \lvert 0 \rangle + \beta\lvert 1\rangle
\text{ = }(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 i)\lvert 0 \rangle + (\beta_0 + \beta_1 i)\lvert 1 \rangle
$$
and we just rewrite $\psi$, using Euler's formula, to:
$$
\psi = r_\alpha e^{\gamma i}\lvert 0 \rangle + r_\beta e^{\rho i}\lvert 1 \rangle
$$
then map $\psi$ to the equivalent $\psi^{'}$ using the global phase $e^{-\gamma i}$ which gives us:
$$
\psi^{'}=r_\alpha\lvert 0 \rangle + r_\beta e^{(\rho-\gamma)i}\lvert 1 \rangle
$$

Now we have an equivalent state in the form that we like. Some trigonometry  will get us to $\theta$,$\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\phi$ that you can map onto your bloch sphere.

I hope that helps some.

Comment: I just saw your follow-up question.  You can't multiply by i to get what you want because that will change the relative phase between $\lvert 0\rangle$ and $\lvert 1 \rangle$.  But you can multiply by $e^{\gamma i}$ to get to where you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! It’s hard to find information on this stuff lol, my quantum computing class is supposed to be the easy part right now

Comment: Yea it can all be overwhelming.  One thing I want to point out is that in your first state, you seem to have a $\sqrt{i}$ .  If i is truly under the radical, remember to expand it out with $\sqrt{i} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} (1 + i)$